# How to turn off new feature in Mathematica

Tags: front-end, notebooks, editing

Mathematica recently added a new feature where an "x" appears to the right of input that does not make sense.  See video below.  Notice that as I start typing an x appears to the right.

[image]

This is generally not a problem for me.  However, I find that the x sometimes appears in textual content.  I am not able to keep the textual material and delete the x.  The easiest fix for me to is to completely turn off this feature.  Is this possible?

I am running Mathematica 11.1

Edit 1:  Below is a pic of the issue I am having. That little x should not be there.

[image]

The underlying code using Command+Shift+E is:

```
Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[GridBox[{
    {
     RowBox[{
      RowBox[{"8.", "\[AlignmentMarker]  ", "c", " ", 
       StyleBox["0",
        FontWeight->"Bold"]}], "=", 
      StyleBox["0",
       FontWeight->"Bold"]}], 
     StyleBox[
      RowBox[{"Multiplication", " ", "by", " ", "zero", " ", "vector"}], "TypesetAnnotationFont"]},
    {
     RowBox[{
      RowBox[{"9.", "\[AlignmentMarker]  ", "1", 
       StyleBox["v",
        FontWeight->"Bold",
        FontSlant->"Plain"]}], "=", 
      StyleBox["v",
       FontWeight->"Bold",
       FontSlant->"Plain"]}], 
     StyleBox[
      RowBox[{"Multiplicative", " ", "identity"}], "TypesetAnnotationFont"]}
   },
   GridBoxAlignment->{"Columns" -> {{"\[AlignmentMarker]", Left}}}], TraditionalForm]], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{3.7103533467950363`*^9}]
```

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag on your *own* questions, as explained in the tag description (regardless of whether or not you are convinced that it is a bug).  That "x" is a multiplication sign.  It only appears when white space (space or new line) is used to denote multiplication.  It is a warning to you that there is a `Times` there, in case you did not intend it.

Comment: Thank you.  I will not use the tag bug and will update the question.

Comment: "However, I find that the x sometimes appears in textual content." Now you have the answer about how to turn this off, but I am still curious if you have seen any instances where the appearance of the "x" is truly incorrect (i.e. there is no multiplication there).

Comment: @Szabolcs  - I posted the specific issue I am having above.  Not sure if the x it truly incorrect or not.  But I definitely don't want the x there. Thank you.

Comment: Do you think this justifies as being a bug as it appears in textual content?

Comment: Note that you can add a `StyleBox` with `AutoMultiplicationSymbol->False` around the RowBox, or as an option at the Cell level, to make sure it isn't displayed irrespective of the setting at the global level.  AutoMultiplicationSymbol has long been enable by default, but it has been made smarter in 11.1.  If you do `ToExpression[RowBox[{"9.", "\[AlignmentMarker]  ", "1", 
  StyleBox["v", FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSlant -> "Plain"]}],StandardForm,Hold]//FullForm`, you'll get the result `Hold[Times[9.,1,v]]`, so the addition of the implied multiplication is quite right in this case.